# Azure Auto Heal Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cloud

What are exactly meanings of the Azure Auto Heal Triggers below ? What is the difference between **requests** and **slowRequests**? I am looking for examples of the usage of the triggers, especially for the **requests** parameter.

```
{
 "privateBytesInKB": 0,
  "requests": {
    "count": 0,
    "timeInterval": ""
  },
  "slowRequests": {
    "count": 0,
    "timeInterval": "",
    "timeTaken": ""
  },
  "statusCodes": [
    {
      "count": 0,
      "status": 0,
      "subStatus": 0,
      "timeInterval": "",
      "win32Status": 0
    } 
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are easily found on the Internet, like [this doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/):

> **Scenario 1 – “Recycling based on Request count”**
>
> Consider a scenario where you have a need to recycle your application automatically after it has served X number of requests in Y amount of time. You know that it just doesn’t scale well after huge influx of requests in short amount of time. You want to detect this condition and recycle worker process automatically and log an event.

> **Scenario 2 – “Recycling based on slow requests”**
>
> Consider a scenario where the performance of your application starts degrading and several pages start taking longer time to render. You would like to detect this situation and recycle worker process automatically.

So, the difference between requests and slow requests triggers is the way Auto-Healing is triggered: based on the number of requests in a given timeperiod or the number of slow requests (based on their duration) in a given timeperiod.